# Bootstrap panel collapse onclick event and glyphicons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

I'm fairly new to bootstraps and I am currently trying to add an onclick event for a button, which would only open my main bootstrap panel.

Here's the part of the HTML code where my bootstrap panels are located;

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-groupMain">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Main panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Sub panels -->
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <!-- Sub panel 1 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Sub panel 1</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentOne"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 2 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Sub panel 2</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="day" data-name="Tuesday"></div>
                          <p id="contentTwo"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 3 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Sub panel 3</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentThree"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 4 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Sub panel 4</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentFour"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 5 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Sub panel 5</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentFive"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for the glyphicons I've tried this code, but it only toggles the change when you open/close the same sub panel, so is there any easy way for the glyphicon to change when you open different sub panels?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function () {
            $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-
            down').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        });
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/mc3z6ad3/2/

```js
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
if( $(this).closest('div.panel-heading').next('div.collapse').hasClass('in')){
 $(this).next('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
}else{
 $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').next('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  
 $(this).next('span').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
}
 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-groupMain">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Main panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Sub panels -->
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <!-- Sub panel 1 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Sub panel 1</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentOne"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 2 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Sub panel 2</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="day" data-name="Tuesday"></div>
                          <p id="contentTwo"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 3 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Sub panel 3</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentThree"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 4 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Sub panel 4</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentFour"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 5 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Sub panel 5</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentFive"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IIarim. Check the updated solution. Previous solution was having a bug, I fixed it in this. Scenario, open **SubPanel 1** then close **SubPanel 1** glyphicon changes.

Comment: @IlariM one more bug in the code, click open a sub panel and then close main panel, the chevron changes on the open panel, its fixed in my code :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
if( $(this).closest('div.panel-heading').next('div.collapse').hasClass('in')){
$(this).next('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
}else{
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').next('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  
$(this).next('span').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
}

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-groupMain">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Main panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Sub panels -->
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <!-- Sub panel 1 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Sub panel 1</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentOne"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 2 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Sub panel 2</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="day" data-name="Tuesday"></div>
                          <p id="contentTwo"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 3 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">Sub panel 3</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentThree"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 4 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">Sub panel 4</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentFour"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Sub panel 5 -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">Sub panel 5</a>
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></span>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p id="contentFive"></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The span wasn't inside the `a` so you need to navigate up to the parent and find from there. I added `parent()` to your line of code. I also added logic to reset other heading panels

Comment: There is a bug in your code, I'm really sorry to say that. Scenario, open up **SubPanel 1**, then open **SubPanel 2** without closing **SubPanel 1** & again click on **SubPanel1**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Shiladitya Yes this is a problem I am trying to solve at the moment.

Comment: @Shiladitya its been fixed

Comment: @Deckerz Thank you it's working great! So the onclick event for the button to open the main panel would work similar?

Comment: @Deckerz. One more bug in your updated code. Scenario, open **SubPanel 1** & then close **SubPanel 1**, glyphicon still remains same. Check it.